# Web client for Apache Axis2 web service

Tags: java, soa, apache-axis

I have this application written in java to calculate pageranks. And the application takes in a file in specified format, parses it , generates the network graph and adjacency matrix, calculates pageranks and displays the top 20 pageranks. This is a standalone app. I need to build a webservice for this app to be 
deployed on Tomcat using Apache Axis2 and Java.

I am interested in designing a webapp (client) for this webservice that takes a file on the client's computer as input , sends it to the webservice for pagerank calculation and send results back to the client, so that it can display them on the webpage.

Any ideas on what technologies are needed to design the client, that invokes the webservice with the file to be processed and displays the results sent back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correctly you just have to code your requirements for the client. The part to deal with the webservice you normaly will use a generator to parse your wsdl into java classes (assuming your using java for the client too). If you use eclipse have a look at New -> Web Services -> Web Service Client. If your Client is not written in Java you should look for a appropriate generator.

Comment: @kukudas I need a client that can be hosted on a webserver. A client that accepts a file as Input, passes it on to the Webservice and displays the results retrieved. Also, i assume you installed WTP plugin for Eclipse, but i am not. Thanks.